# Parallel looping with Java Streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists. One shows number of successful attempts for each individual in a group of people for some game.

```
public class SuccessfulAttempts{
    String name;
    int successCount;
}

List<SuccessfulAttempts> success;
```

And total number of attempts for each individual.

```
public class TotalAttempts{
    String name;
    int totalCount;
}

List<TotalAttempts> total;
```

And I want to show the percentage success for each person in the group.

```
public class PercentageSuccess{
    String name;
    float percentage;
}

List<PercentageSuccess> percentage;
```

And assume I have populate first two lists like this.

```
success.add(new SuccessfulAttempts(Alice, 4));
success.add(new SuccessfulAttempts(Bob, 7));

total.add(new TotalAttempts(Alice, 5));
total.add(new TotalAttempts(Bob, 10));
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage success for each person using Java Streams. So I actually need this kind of a result for the list `List<PercentageSuccess> percentage`.

```
new PercentageSuccess(Alice, 80);
new PercentageSuccess(Bob, 70);
```

And I want to calculate them (Alice's percentage and Bob's percentage) in ***parallel*** (I know how to do sequentially using a loop). How I can achieve this with Java Streams (or any other simple way)??

Comment: Alice's percentage should be 4/5=80% ?

Comment: Why are you keeping  attempts / sucesses in separate structures in a first place?

Comment: @Jerry06 correct. edited :))

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda with my data (no-sql) level implementation, it is hard to do in other way. :))

Comment: ...  if you have no-sql db then you have other options to collate / compute your data.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda I am using hbase, if there's such pls post me a link. :)) on the other hand it was a requirement change (first they said only count, then they wanted percentage not count). So we needed to find an easier way. :))

Comment: you will be able there to store both values on one customer key,   and compute percentage in one map reduce job

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda actually I'm getting values for numberOfSuccess, total  etc., after summing up values for number of rows, not a single one. In that sense extending your solution would not be efficient. :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest converting one of your list to a Map for Easier access of count. Else for each value of one list you've to loop in the other list which will be O(n^2) complexity.

```
List<SuccessfulAttempts> success = new ArrayList<>();
List<TotalAttempts> total = new ArrayList<>();

success.add(new SuccessfulAttempts("Alice", 4));
success.add(new SuccessfulAttempts("Bob", 7));

total.add(new TotalAttempts("Alice", 5));
total.add(new TotalAttempts("Bob", 10));

// First create a Map
Map<String, Integer> attemptsMap = success.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SuccessfulAttempts::getName, SuccessfulAttempts::getSuccessCount));

// Loop through the list of players and calculate percentage.
List<PercentageSuccess> percentage =
    total.parallelStream()
         // Remove players who have not participated from List 'total'. ('attempt' refers to single element in List 'total').
         .filter(attempt -> attemptsMap.containsKey(attempt.getName()))
         // Calculate percentage and create the required object
         .map(attempt -> new PercentageSuccess(attempt.getName(),
                    ((attemptsMap.get(attempt.getName()) * 100) / attempt.getTotalCount())))
         // Collect it back to list
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

percentage.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found Aetoros's solution as an easier one. isn't it? is their any reason to go with yours not Aetoros's ?? :))

Comment: If your data is saved exactly in the same order and your sure even in future the order won't get mixed, then you can definitely go with Aetoros's answer :) As a matter of fact, its better to go with that approach as index based in better than creating a map. Also, just make sure there will definitely be an entry in successfulAttempts list for every value in totalAttempts (Say no successful attempts were made, will there at least be a value of 0 saved?) in these scenario's you again can't go with index based approach.

Comment: In my case the orders will not be a problem, but the latter (0 value) might be, and it can cause order also. I'll have a look an update. :))

Comment: Thnx a lot for further thinking. Anyhow I am not sure you came up with the correct time complexity since this is in parallel processing. In sequential you are correct. :))

Answer (score 1):

If arrays are of same  same `size` and correctly ordered, you can use integer indexes to access original list elements.

```
List<PercentageSuccess> result = IntStream.range(0, size).parallel().mapToObj(index -> /*get the elements and construct percentage progress for person with given index*/).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This means you have to create a method or custructor for PercentageSuccess which construncts a percentage for given SuccessAttempts and TotalAttempts.

```
PercentageSuccess(SuccessfulAttempts success, TotalAttempts total) {
    this.name = success.name;
    this.percentage = (float) success.successCount / (float) total.totalCount;
}
```

Then you construct a stream of integers from 0 to size which is parallel:

```
IntStream.range(0, size).parallel()
```

this is actually parallel for loop. Then turn each integer into PercentageSuccess of index'th person (note that you must enshure that lists are of same size and not shuffled, otherwice my code is not correct).

```
.mapToObj(index -> new PercentageSuccess(success.get(index), total.get(index))
```

and finally turn Stream to List with

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Also, this approach is not optimal in case `success` or `total` are LinkedList or other list implementation with O(n) cost of accessing element by index.

Comment: Could you please show the working line of code without your block comment? :)) And add some more explanation pls. :))

Comment: looks the simplest solution, will update you after I test. :))

Comment: Simplest, but has limitations

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<PercentageAttempts> percentage(List<SuccessfulAttempts> success, List<TotalAttempts> total) {

    Map<String, Integer> successMap = success.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(SuccessfulAttempts::getName, SuccessfulAttempts::getSuccessCount, (a, b) -> a + b));

    Map<String, Integer> totalMap = total.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(TotalAttempts::getName, TotalAttempts::getTotalCount));

    return successMap.entrySet().parallelStream().map(entry -> new PercentageAttempts(entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue() * 1.0f / totalMap.get(entry.getKey()) * 100))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found Aetoros's solution as an easier one. isn't it? is their any reason to go with yours not Aetoros's ?? :))

Comment: @SupunWijerathne see his comments.. about input not shuffled, also what will happen if there are multiple entries like *Alice, 4* then later *Alice, 5*. whatever fits your needs is good enough, don't over think it.

Comment: actually in my case it is not shuffled anyway. :)) so would it make your answer simpler? if so could you pls add that to your answer? pls dnt delete current one. :))